# Configuring CUPS to password protect IPP shared printers with windows compatibilty

Tags: windows, cups, printing

With my current configuration, printers can be installed on windows, but the wizard doesn't prompt for credentials and printing is not possible.
Despite [supplying the credentials in the url](https://superuser.com/questions/1170767/how-can-i-use-cups-basic-authentication-from-a-windows-client) (`http://some_user:password@serverip:port/printers/myprinter`), windows is persistently using the local account name and does not seem to attempt basic auth (as described in the linked post).

```
Denying user "local_windows_user" access to printer "myprinter"...
Print-Job client-error-not-authorized: Not allowed to print.
[Client x] Returning IPP client-error-not-authorized for Print-Job
```

Am I missing something in my configuration so that the windows client is not forced to prompt for a password? Even configuring the port in windows and specifying credentials there doesn't change the outcome.
Might it be possible to make CUPS only look at the url for authentication as a workaround?

I have tried using basic auth on locations that are currently allowed, but that led to the install failing instead of a prompt so far.

some_user is allowed to print with myprinter via the web interface.
when credentials are prompted, the connection is upgraded to https.
Testing with `DefaultEncryption Never` did not change the result.

---

**cupsd.conf**

```
Listen localhost:631
Listen serverip:port

Browsing On
BrowseLocalProtocols dnssd

DefaultAuthType Basic

<Location />
  Order allow,deny 
</Location>
    
# Restrict access to the admin pages...
<Location /admin>
  AuthType Default
  Order allow,deny
  Require user @SYSTEM
</Location>

# Restrict access to configuration files...
<Location /admin/conf>
  AuthType Default
  Require user @SYSTEM
  Order allow,deny
</Location>

# Restrict access to log files...
<Location /admin/log>
  AuthType Default
  Require user @SYSTEM
  Order allow,deny
</Location>

# Set the default printer/job policies...
<Policy default>
  # Job/subscription privacy...
  JobPrivateAccess default
  JobPrivateValues default
  SubscriptionPrivateAccess default
  SubscriptionPrivateValues default

  <Limit Get-Printer-Attributes>
    #AuthType Default
    Order allow, deny
  </Limit>

  <Limit Create-Job Print-Job Print-URI Validate-Job>
    Order deny, allow
    AuthType Basic
  </Limit>

[ommitted]
```

**Versions**

```
Server: Fedora 37 Server
Cups Version: cups-2.4.2-5.fc37
Windows Version: Windows 10 Pro 21H2 (tested, not working), Windows 10 Pro 22H2 (tested, not working)
```

**Notes**

Tested on plain Linux Mint 21.1 Live. All printers are automatically detected and prompt for password on printing. On the server, the user is logged as `some_user`.

---

**When requiring basic auth for `Get-Printer-Attributes`**

Windows will show a generic error "could not connect.. verify printer name, etc..."

Cups log:

```
POST /printers/myprinter HTTP/1.1
cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients", busy="Active clients"
[Client 6] Read: status=200, state=6
[Client 6] No authentication data provided.
[Client 6] 2.0 Get-Printer-Attributes 6
Get-Printer-Attributes ipp://some_user:password@serverip:port/printers/myprinter
cupsdIsAuthorized: username=""
[Client 6] Returning HTTP not authorized for Get-Printer-Attributes (ipp://some_user:password@serverip:port/printers/myprinter
[Client 6] cupsdSendHeader: code=426, type="text/html", auth_type=1
[Client 6] HTTP_STATE_WAITING Closing for error 32 (Broken pipe)
[Client 6] Closing connection.
cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Active clients"
```

Visiting the URL in the browser, i get a warning: "you are about to login with username..., but the page doesn't require auth". If I proceed, i get to a redirect page, which reloads after ~1s and only then I'm prompted for credentials. Maybe the html response before the prompt for basic auth is what trips Windows up.

**When trying to add an URL to a generic webserver with basic auth**

In this case, Windows (and a browser) will prompt for a password right away.

Comment: What version of Windows do the clients have?  Does it work from Linux client?

Comment: @tukan I've updated my question. Yes, it does seem to work flawlessly on a Linux client.

Comment: Great. So that means the problem is on the client side. Can you test it on older windows? Like Win10 1903? Win7?

Comment: Which edition of Windows do you have? *Home*, *Pro*, *Enterprise*?

Comment: @tukan unfortunately, i don't currently have older versions available. It's pro.

Comment: *Pro* should be ok.  I saw quite some patches for IPP probably some bug.  Just to make sure do you have the "Internet Printing Client" selected in the Windows features?

Comment: @tukan thanks for having a look. Yes, it's enabled. I've also tried another method of adding the printer: `Add a printer using a TCP/IP address or hostname` and explicitly selecting IPP. Even here, no prompt for password if `Get-Printer-Attributes` doesn't require one and an error when it requires one. I've updated my question with logs.

Comment: @tukan on the other hand, is username and password in the url really no auth data? Maybe it's a problem with cups as well.

Comment: @tukan when enabling basic auth for everything and visiting the url in the browser, i get a warning: "you are about to login with username..., but the page doesn't require auth". If I proceed, i get to a redirect page, which reloads after ~1s and only then I'm prompted for credentials. Maybe that is what trips Windows up.

Comment: @tukan i have confirmed this by setting up a webserver with basic auth and trying to add it as a printer. Here, I get a prompt in the browser right away and Windows also prompts for creds.

Comment: It is hard to say on which side is the error as CUPS works correctly when client is linux.  That is the reason why I wanted to try older windows version. I still think the issue could be somewhere in the windows client, but hard to say from far away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved for http connections, not sure about https. I believe the self-signed certificate in combination with just an IP address is causing problems there. It may be possible to add it to trusted root certs, but it looks like Windows isn't content with just that. If I can believe the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/printing/error-occurs-when-adding-ipp-printer) (which may be outdated), it still relies on Internet Explorer. So if it is opened there without errors, it should also connect a printer.

Basically, using `Require [user or group]` and `AuthType Basic` will cause CUPS to prompt for credentials right away, but that alone is not enough, because CUPS will try to upgrade the connection to https (returning a html page instead of a prompt).

Adding `DefaultEncryption IfRequested` in the general section will prevent that behaviour and the prompt is picked up by Windows.